# upgrading greybox with fancybox not working

Tags: jquery, fancybox, greybox

I was using grey box which is working fine. But I try to upgrade to fancybox but it is redirecting to the link. Any one please help

Here is my code  :

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.1"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.1" media="screen" />
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var GB_ROOT_DIR = "greybox/";
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/AJS.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/AJS_fx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/gb_scripts.js"></script>
<link href="greybox/gb_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("body").on("click",".fancybox",function() {
      link=($(this).attr('href'));
            $.fancybox({
            'width'                : '1000',
            'href'                 : link,
            'height'            : '750',
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'        : 'none',
            'transitionOut'        : 'none',
            'type'                : 'iframe'
            }); 
       event.preventDefault();
           });
 });
</script>  
</head>
<body>
<a class="fancybox" href="detail.php">Detail</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there anything I have to add additional?

Comment: Is there any output in you javascript console? If so please paste it here. Given the description you gave, it seems like there's a JS error preventing further instructions from being executed.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  on line 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be grey box is confilicting with fancy box.  Remove the greybox scripts  and try. it will work

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.1"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.1" media="screen" />

<!--
<script type="text/javascript">
   var GB_ROOT_DIR = "greybox/";
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/AJS.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/AJS_fx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/gb_scripts.js"></script>
<link href="greybox/gb_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
-->
```

Comment: Not sure they will conflict since they seem to use different function names but it sure couldn't hurt to remove them if he switches to fancybox plus it'll make the page load faster.

Comment: Thanks .when I comment like above it is working fine.